# can we pass entire model to javascript asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem that on javascript call for the form submit , the model gets updated from controller ,but it is not updating in the view. I am thinking to update the model to new model values in javascript . so that the view shows the latest model values
 can that be done?

thanks,
michael

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to have the form submit via AJAX, have the controller action return a new view, and update the DOM on request callback?

Comment: the controller returns to same view with an updated model and i can't submit through ajax as i am uploading a file.after submit is pressed the model is not updating it is same as previous model and once again i come to that page then the model is updated. so i think to update the model on same page in javascript. can that be done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand! You say you update the model via the controller and then return the same view with an updated model. How are you submitting the form? What's happening with the HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear and you provided no source code which makes things even more unclear. From the various comments you may have posted I assume that you are trying to update some model value inside the POST action without removing it from the model state and when the same view is rendered again the old values are displayed.

So I suppose you have a view model that looks something close to this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SomeValue = "initial value"
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // Notice how the SomeValue property is removed from the
        // model state because we are updating its value and so that
        // html helpers don't use the old value
        ModelState.Remove("SomeValue");
        model.SomeValue = "some new value";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeValue) %>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeValue) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="file">Attachment</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: darin for wht u have done, i really thank you. but i haven't shown the source code bcoz the question is a partial problem .now i figured out and the above will work fine ,but in my scenario i have two form tags so if i think what ever u have added to first form to stay back in same page i targeted this form to an iframe as document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 document.getElementById(form_id).target = iFrame_id; hence the iframe is not updating the model data after coming back from controller.